# How does offer creation impact fund requirement of an account?

Tags: ripple

How much does each offer created increase the XRP requirement on that account?

Does it relate to PayerGets?

Is it cleared once I cancel the offer?

Comment: Abrkn, what is PayerGets?

Comment: see https://ripple.com/wiki/Transaction_Format under OfferCreate

Comment: So you mean `TakerGets`?

Answer (score 1):

Every entry in the state tree of the ledger requires 12.5 XRP reserve, it doesn't matter if it's a trade offer or a trust-line. When the entry disappears from the ledger (by getting filled or being canceled), the reserves can be moved again.

The only exception is the account entry, which requires 50 XRP instead of 12.5 XRP and is perpetual (because accounts cannot be deleted).

See https://ripple.com/wiki/Reserves for details and the current reserve requirements (they can and have changed).

It is not related with the field TakerGets of the message OfferCreate.

Answer (score 0):

(jed2 on irc) abrkn: 50 xrp. Doesn't matter what the offer is for. It is cleared when the offer is canceled (or fulfilled).

Comment: "When the offer is"... what? I guess he meant "either fulfilled or canceled"?

Comment: Yes, I believe that was a bad paste. It is cleared when cancelled.